# Airflow scheduler --pid command not work?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I would like to ask the question about whether command of Apache Airflow is work or not. Thank you.

OS Version: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Apache Airflow Version: 2.2.5

Airflow Command:
`airflow scheduler --pid /xxx/xxx.pid`

Expected Result: process id file will exist in /xxx/xxx.pid

Answer (score 1):

You must run [`airflow scheduler` command](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.2.5/airflow/cli/commands/scheduler_command.py#L57) with the [`daemon` option](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.2.5/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py#L179) together with the `pid` option.

Run

```
airflow schedule -D --pid /xxx/xxx.pid
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. I have tried to run the command ```airflow schedule -D --pid /xxx/xxx.pid```, however, it seems that no pid file created.